# java, static field or instance field?

Tags: java

I am designing a library which will be used by third part client code.In my library, we create instance for 'SocketJobModel ' class, which is used to send data through socket. In all instance objects of `SocketJobModel` , we need to do some logging job, currently I let all instance objects of `SocketJobModel` share the same logging object through a static filed of `Factory` class, should I do this ? If my `IMessageLogger` object is thread safe, is that ok ?

```
public class Factory {

    static IMessageLogger msgLogger;

    public static SocketJobModel create(){
        return new SocketJobModel();
    }
}
```

**edit**

Note: `IMessageLogger` will be implemented by client code.And client code may use different logging frameworks, log4j and jdk logging or something else. This interface server as a adapter for different logging mechanism used by client code. And why I want to use a static field at the first place?  to reduce memory usage.

Comment: shouldnt you add the IMessageLogger msgLogger inside the SocketJobModel?

Answer (score 0):

How can you be sure that `IMessageLogger` is thread-safe if that's implemented by client code?

Maybe you can leave the retrieval of the logger instance to to `IMessageLogger` itself, by implementing a `getLogger` method in the interface? In this way client code may decide how to supply a `Logger` instance (be it static or not)

Comment: In my documentation, I said, "implementation of IMessageLogger must be thread-safe"

Comment: You don't guarantee that the client might follow your requirement, unless you have a review process in place.